Not hitting the correct endpoint with wp backbone models using wp.api.models.Post.extend
I'm creating a plugin that has a custom post type called tasks. I would like to use backbone.js models to perform crud operations to tasks via wp rest api. When I try to extend the models, following the docs here https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/, I get an error: jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1:2
GET http://easy-editor:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1220 404 (Not Found)
The request is to wp/v2/posts instead of wp/v2/task.
This is my code
wp.api.loadPromise.done(function() {
    
const TaskModel = wp.api.models.Post.extend( {
    urlRoot: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/task',
    defaults: {
      type: 'task',
    },
  } );

  task.fetch().then( ( response ) => {
    console.log( 'success', response );
  }).catch( ( error ) => {
    console.log( "error", error );
  });

});

My CPT registration:
public function register_custom_post_type()
    {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Tasks', 'Post Type General Name', 'easy-editor'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Task', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'easy-editor'),
            'add_new' => _x('New Task', 'Task', 'easy-editor'), // Added
            'add_new_item' => __('New Task', 'easy-editor'), // Added
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Task', 'easy-editor'),
            'new_item' => __('New Task', 'easy-editor'),
            'view_item' => __('View Task', 'easy-editor'),
            'view_items' => __('View Tasks', 'easy-editor'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Tasks', 'easy-editor'),
            'not_found' => __('No Tasks found', 'easy-editor'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Tasks found in Trash', 'easy-editor'),
            'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Task:', 'easy-editor'),
            'all_items' => __('All Tasks', 'easy-editor'),
            'archives' => __('Task Archives', 'easy-editor'),
            'attributes' => __('Task Attributes', 'easy-editor'),
            // Additional labels can be added here
        );

        $args = array(
            'label' => __('Task', 'easy-editor'),
            'labels' => $labels,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'author'),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-list-view',
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'rest_base'     => 'task', // Ensures the REST API endpoint is /wp/v2/task
            'can_export' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'task',
            // Additional arguments can be added here
        );

        register_post_type('task', $args);
    }

Does anyone know why the api request is to /posts/ instead of task? The docs are not very comprehensive with this.
(yes i know i should pluralize task to tasks)

The answer to this can be found here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378711/url-issue-retrieving-custom-post-types-using-backbone-js-api
